# How to work with the MCP1702?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo

I'm reading the [MCP1702 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22008E.pdf) and there's the typical circuit on page 2 depicting a 9V source and a 3.3V 50mA output.

My question is: How come the current output is 50mA when the spec says that when Vr < 2.5V, Vin > 3.45V the min. output current is 200mA? How is the output current determined? Why is it 50mA?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Certainly linked to page 2 internal circuit.

Comment: Read the data sheet properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's an example circuit. They could have written 35mA.
2. Power dissipation is (Vin - Vout) * IL, so 285mW in this example.
   So in the SOT-23 case we'd have a junction temperature rise of about
   96°C. If we allow a maximum junction temperature of 125°C (the highest **steady state** temperature for which the characteristics are guaranteed- see table below), the
   circuit would be good for an ambient up to 29°C, which isn't very
   impressive. Maybe they **should** have written 35mA. It would be better in the other packages. SOT-89 would only rise 44°C so would be good to ambient 81°C (or higher current at a lower ambient).

These numbers are calculated from this table:

[image]

They may be **optimistic** because they assume a 4-layer board, probably with ground and power planes, so caveat emptor. Edit: Yes, [it](http://www.jedec.org/sites/default/files/docs/jesd51-12.pdf) does assume 1-oz power and ground planes, so if your design is 1 or 2 layer it will not perform as well:

[image]

If you only require brief pulses of current from the source, such that the junction does not heat excessively, the higher current rating may indeed apply, but you would have to pay attention to the transient thermal characteristics to determine if those operational conditions were acceptable.

In design it's important to make sure that **all** the constraints are satisfied. It's no good saying that the regulator is supplying current as specified if it shuts down a second later (and eventually fries) due to overheating.

Comment: So, do you mean that they could have written any figure <250mA for Iout because it's not the LDO that determines the amount of current that can be drawn but it is the device drawing the current?

Comment: Yes, that is true, but writing 200mA would be excessively misleading (*even* for a data sheet) because there would be **no** reasonable circumstances under which a continuous current of (say) 200mA would be acceptable with a 9V input and 3.3V output (1.1W dissipation). 50mA is also probably a more realistic maximum under which you'd use such a circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the datasheet carefully.  It says that for flavors with output voltages (Vr) of 2.5 V or more, the output current can be up to 250 mA.  The lower output voltage variants have less output current capability.  The datasheet then lists the maximum current capability for different Vin levels.  This is all quite clear and well specified.  I don't understand what it confusing about this.

As for the circuit on page 2, it is completely consistant with the specifications on the next page.  In this case, Vin = 9V and Vr = 3.3.  According to the specs, the part in that case is capable of 250 mA output minimum.  They are running it at 50 mA.  Since 50 mA ≤
250 mA, I again don't see a problem.  The circuit they show uses the device within spec.  Note that this is just a *example* circuit, and you are free to make your own circuit and use the device within any of the conditions specified on page 3.

Note also that in this example circuit the chip is dropping 5.7 V.  That times 50 mA means it is dissipating 285 mW.  With such a large voltage drop, the power dissipation becomes the limiting factor on output current, not the maximum output current spec.  Again, it's a *example*.  (Of course one is left to wonder why use a LDO when there is 5.7 V of headroom available, but that's a different issue).

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because of power dissipation, thermal resistance of the package & max junction temperature.

With 9V in, 3.3V out and 50mA, thats 285mW dissipation for the device.

The SOT-23 package has a Junction-Ambient thermal resistance of 336C/W, so that means at 285mW the device's internals will be almost 96C above ambient.

The max junction temperature is 150C, so under those conditions, the highest ambient temperature at which it can operate is 56C - which is not unexpectedly high if its in a sealed enclosure with other power-dissipating stuff.